# How to take integer input with scanf in C without using arrays?

Tags: c, debugging, input, scanf

I want to take input like the following:

*Write: 1 5 3*

**OR**

*Write: 1 2*

**OR**

*Write: 2 4 9 4*

**OR**

*Write: (press Enter directly)*

However, problem is that I want to take max 5 integer or less. Therefore, I wrote this expression:

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
```

When I did that, if I write integers, such as 1 4 6, the program continues to want integers until I complete the number of integers to 5.

Also, sometimes, I need to skip this part by pressing enter without writing an integer. But, I can not implement that.

I did that also:

```
 scanf("%d%c", &firstStore,&control);
    if(control==' ')
    {
        scanf("%d%c", &secondStore,&control);
        if(control==' ')
        {
            scanf("%d%c", &thirdStore,&control);
            if(control==' ')
            {
                scanf("%d%c", &fourthStore,&control);
                if(control==' ')
                {
                    scanf("%d", &fifthStore);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that I can not skip this part if I want. I mean this code wants to take minimum one integer always.

**RULE:**

*The usage of arrays is banned.*

Comment: Don't tag a question that asks about "`scanf()` in C" with the C++ tag; it will only earn you opprobrium and downvotes.

Comment: Do you have in mind reading up to 5 integers from a single line?  Remember that `scanf()` cares not in the slightest about newlines — they are just white space to be consumed.  If you want line-based input, read the line (e.g. with standard C `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`) and then parse it with `sscanf()`.  And then you can check the return value from `sscanf()` to work out how many integers were read.  The blanks in the format string are unnecessary (`%d` will skip white space anyway) but harmless.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Using `fgets` or `getline` violates OP's restriction of not being allowed to use arrays. However, violating this rule is probably unavoidable, as all 3 answers to this question (including my own) violate this rule. I am unable to think of any clean solultion which does not violate this rule.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel — ugh!  Yes, there is no clean solution not using a character array to store the line.  There are unclean solutions reading a character at a time and doing conversions as needed and so on — the function would have to be prepared to diagnose "blank/tab delimiter", "newline delimiter", "other delimiter" and EOF, as well as non-number and any other problems.  Definitely not nice!  But, using `scanf()` completely precludes control over newlines — the `%d` format skips leading white space (including newlines) regardless of what you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all of the other answers, the following solution violates the rule of not using arrays, because I cannot think of any clean solution to the problem which does not use them.

The problem with using `scanf` is that it will treat spaces and newline characters equally. This is not what you want.

For line-based user input, it makes more sense to always read one line at a time, and treat every line individually. In order to read one line of user input as a string, you can use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). You can then convert this string to numbers using the function [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Here is a solution that uses the function `sscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop
    {
        char line[200];
        int numbers[5];
        int num_numbers;

        //prompt user for input
        printf( "Please enter up to 5 numbers: " );

        //attempt to read one line of input from user
        if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
            break;

        //verify that line was not too long for input buffer
        if ( strchr( line, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            printf( "Line too long for input buffer!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //attempt to convert string to numbers
        num_numbers = sscanf(
            line,
            "%d %d %d %d %d",
            &numbers[0], &numbers[1], &numbers[2],
            &numbers[3], &numbers[4]
        );

        //print result
        if  ( num_numbers == 0 || num_numbers == EOF )
        {
            printf( "Was not able to match any numbers.\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Successfully matched %d numbers:\n", num_numbers );
            for ( int i = 0; i < num_numbers; i++ )
            {
                printf( "%d\n", numbers[i] );
            }
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter up to 5 numbers: 20 30 35 40
Successfully matched 4 numbers:
20
30
35
40

Please enter up to 5 numbers: 
Was not able to match any numbers.

Please enter up to 5 numbers: 12 17
Successfully matched 2 numbers:
12
17

Please enter up to 5 numbers: 5
Successfully matched 1 numbers:
5
```

Here is a solution which uses the function `strtol` instead of `sscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS 5

int main( void )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop
    {
        char line[200], *p = line, *q;
        long numbers[MAX_NUMBERS];
        int num_numbers = 0;

        //prompt user for input
        printf( "Please enter up to 5 numbers: " );

        //attempt to read one line of input from user
        if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
            break;

        //verify that line was not too long for input buffer
        if ( strchr( line, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            printf( "Line too long for input buffer!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //convert as many numbers as possible
        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++ )
        {
            numbers[i] = strtol( p, &q, 10 );
            if ( p == q )
                break;

            p = q;
            num_numbers++;
        }

        //print result
        if  ( num_numbers == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Was not able to match any numbers.\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Successfully matched %d numbers:\n", num_numbers );
            for ( int i = 0; i < num_numbers; i++ )
            {
                printf( "%ld\n", numbers[i] );
            }
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

This second program has exactly the same output as the first program.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to get a whole line and then parse it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char line[1024];
    if (fgets(line, 1024, stdin) == NULL) {
        perror("Error occured");
        return 2;
    }
    if (line[strlen(line)-1] != '\n') {
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    } else {
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (char * word = strtok(line, " "); word; word = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        int number = atoi(word);
        // do something with your number
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check that `fgets()` did not return NULL before using the result.  It is often better (more nearly bullet-proof) to use `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';` to zap the newline at the end of the string — it works correctly if there is no newline, whereas what you've got zaps the last character of the string, which might not be a newline if the input line was too long.

Comment: Yep, you are totally right. I will fix it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `scanf()`.

From the [man page of `scanf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) :

> On success, these functions return the number of input items
> successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than
> provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching
> failure.

So your code should something like :?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    while ((scanf("%d")) == 1) {
        /* perform actions */
    }


    return 0;
}
```

To implement the part in which you don't type anything, you have to use a function other than `scanf()`. Consider `fgets()` or `getchar()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    char buff[500];

    while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (buff[0] == '\n') { /* empty - just newline character */
            continue;
        }

        if (sscanf(buff, "%d", &n) != 1) { /* unsuccessful conversion */
            exit(1);
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

This will work considering each line has a single number or you type a single number each time. If your line has multiple numbers, you will have to parse it differently, possibly by using `strtok()` or by modifying `sscanf()`.

You can use the `%n` format and loop so you can check the whole string using `sscanf()`.

From the man page for `%n`:

> Nothing is expected; instead, the number of characters
> consumed thus far from the input is stored through the
> next pointer, which must be a pointer to int, or variant
> whose size matches the (optionally) supplied integer
> length modifier.

So you could replace the if block with something like:

```
    int char_read;
    int start = 0;

    while (start < sizeof(buff) && 
    sscanf(&buff[start], "%d%n", &n, &char_read) == 1) { /* 1 successful conversion */
        printf("%d\n", n);
        start += char_read;
    }
```

[Working example](https://godbolt.org/z/TE4hhe718)